# Difference between these two accessor/getter/setter methods?

Tags: .net, get, set, accessor

Whats the difference now between doing this:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

and this:

```
public string Title;
```

Back in the day people always said use accessor methods with private variables called by the public accessor, now that .net has made get; set; statements so simplified that they look almost the same without the private variable as just using a public only variable, so whats the point and difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195075/clean-code-should-objects-have-public-properties

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properties vs. Fields: Need help grasping the uses of Properties over Fields.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069901/properties-vs-fields-need-help-grasping-the-uses-of-properties-over-fields)

Comment: I understand the need for properties over fields, but in that syntax, there is no difference now?

Comment: The differences are still the same. What's happened is that property syntax has started to look more like field syntax. But it's just syntax: they're completely different underneath.

Comment: Properties should start with capital letter (since they are public) and fields (which should always be private) should not. Properties have {} in signature and fields do not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-implemented getters and setters vs. public fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111461/auto-implemented-getters-and-setters-vs-public-fields)

Answer (score 8):

I have an article on this: [Why properties matter](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter8/PropertiesMatter.aspx).

In short: properties are part of an API. Fields are part of an implementation. Don't expose your implementation to the world. You can change an automatically implemented property to have more behaviour (maybe logging, for example) in a source and binary compatible way. You can't do that with a field.

Answer (score 2):

The first one

```
public string Title { get; set; }
```

is a property (Which is in fact a function).

The second one

```
public string Title;
```

Is a field.

It is good to use properties to hide the implementation (Encapsulation).

Comment: BUt there is not implmentation being hidden here?

Comment: Indeed there is not. But you might add one someday or will arise the need to change the internal implementation so you will be able to do it without changing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you can't modify the implementation of the accessor (because is not an accessor) without recompiling the dependent assemblies.